# Newbie... Question on halving a recipe

Tags: beer, recipe-scaling

I'm planning on brewing a dead pony club clone, however I don't want to do the full 25L I'd rather do 10L or half it. So if I just half everything on the recipe e.g instead of 2.79kg of pale malt I used 1.4kg and so on with the rest of the malts, hops and yeast.

Would this be the right way to go about halving it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can do that. I'm a newbie too and have been doing this myself, because I can only boil enough for a 10L brew. A couple of bits of advice I would offer are firstly that the dried yeast packs have enough yeast to do 20+ L, so you'll end up with lots of half packets, which keep ok in a ziplock bag the fridge, and secondly don't push the envelope with regards to the available space in your fermentation vessel - leave yourself a bit of head space otherwise any kind of vigorous fermentation will result in yeasty beer bubbling up out of the airlock and going everywhere.